# Connecting line does not show up when using nodes in PSTricks

Tags: miktex, pstricks, pst-node, dvi-mode

I was trying to understand the nodes feature in `pst-node`. I copied the following example exactly as written in the `PSTricks` readme.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node}

\begin{document}
\Rnode{A}{sp} \hskip 2cm \Rnode{B}{Bit}
\ncline{A}{B}
\end{document}

These are the file list in the log
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2012/08/24 v0.53 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2012/12/21 v2.35 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2012/12/21 v2.35 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2014/08/04 1.35 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
pst-node.pro    2011/09/18 v. 1.14, PostScript prologue file (hv)
 ***********
```

I compiled it with XeLaTeX. However, the connecting line between the nodes A and B does not show up. Why?

Comment: This works for me using TL 2014. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using texmaker

Comment: TeXMaker is an editor, not the actual TeX system.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows miktex 2.9

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass` line in your document and recompile it. Then copy the File List that shows up in the log and edit your question to show that list.

Comment: sorry for the appearance of the file list, do you need me to edit it again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26057/discussion-between-sclee-and-alan-munn).

Answer (score 2):

You viewed the dvi output which cannot show graphical elements. View always the pdf output or alternatively go into the setup of MiKTeX (YAP) and choose dvips instead of pk for the rendering of method of YAP.